# How to resolve error "Fatal error: Call to a member function str_get_html() on a non-object"?

Tags: php, arrays, imap, simple-html-dom

I am making a function to download mail data in my DB.Here is my code :

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
global $html;
function getArraySubject($stream,$subject){

$array = imap_search($stream, $subject);
return $array ;
}
// $domain 0 = any domeain from which we are receiving mails
//$case = subject number for ex :- Query, Potential.....
function getDataFromHTML($subjectArray, $domain = 0, $case = 1)
{
$completeArray = array();
if ($domain == 0 && $case == 1) {
rsort($subjectArray);

foreach($subjectArray as $email_id){

 $body = imap_qprint(imap_body($stream,$email_id));
    $my_file = 'mail-data.txt';
    file_put_contents($my_file, $body);
    $html = file_get_contents($my_file, true); 
    $htmlData = $html->str_get_html($body);
    $tds = $htmlData->find('table',3)->find('td');
    $num = null;
    $i = 0 ;
     foreach($tds as $td){
      $completeArray['magicbricks']['case1'][$i] = $td->innertext; 
                  $i++;          
            }
}
}
return $completeArray;
}
```

I am getting an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function str_get_html() on a non-object in line no. 25".

How to resolve this issue? please help.

And this is my second file where I am calling above mentioned function.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('functions.php');
// Configure your imap mailboxes
$mailboxes = array(
   array(
    'label'     => 'Label',
    'mailbox'   => '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX',
    'username'  => 'abc@uabc.com',
    'password'  => 'abc246'
)
   );

foreach ($mailboxes as $current_mailbox) {

// Open an IMAP stream to our mailbox
$stream = @imap_open($current_mailbox['mailbox'], $current_mailbox['username'],      $current_mailbox['password']);

if (!$stream) { 
?>
    <p>Could not connect to: <?php echo $current_mailbox['label']?>. Error: <?php echo imap_last_error()?></p>
<?php
} else {
    $sub1 = 'SUBJECT "Query" FROM "magicbricks.com"';


$array1 = getArraySubject($stream,$sub1);

print_r($array1);

    if (!count($array1)){
    ?>
        <p>No e-mails found.</p>
    <?php
    } else {

        $result = getDataFromHTML($array1, $domain = 0, $case = 1);

print_r($result);

    } 
    } 

    // Close our imap stream.
    imap_close($stream); 

} // end foreach
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `$html` in this context is a string so you cannot attach any method to it:

```
$html = file_get_contents($my_file, true); // this is not an instance of simple-html-dom object
$htmlData = $html->str_get_html($body);
            ^
```

Remove that:

```
$htmlData = str_get_html($body); // now this create a simple-html-dom object
```

Comment: thanks but now it shows the same error in next line i.e. in find()

Comment: @shweta what does `mail-data.txt` contain? an html markup template?

Comment: it contains the complete data of mailbox but has no effect even if I remove these 3 lines.  $my_file = 'mail-data.txt';
    file_put_contents($my_file, $body);
    $html = file_get_contents($my_file, true);

Comment: @shweta `it contains the complete data of mailbox` which is what? an html?

Comment: initially I was storing whole data in a txt file but now it is directly coming in $body variable.and yes it a HTML data.

Comment: @shweta it doesn't make sense trying to put inside an html markup in a textfile, then getting it again, why not search directly on `$html = str_get_html($body); $html->find('table', 3)->find('td')`

Answer (score 0):

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
global $html; //This is unnecessary
function getArraySubject($stream,$subject){

$array = imap_search($stream, $subject);
return $array ;
}
// $domain 0 = any domeain from which we are receiving mails
//$case = subject number for ex :- Query, Potential.....
function getDataFromHTML($subjectArray, $domain = 0, $case = 1)
{

//Add this
global $html;


$completeArray = array();
if ($domain == 0 && $case == 1) {
rsort($subjectArray);

foreach($subjectArray as $email_id){

 $body = imap_qprint(imap_body($stream,$email_id));
    $my_file = 'mail-data.txt';
    file_put_contents($my_file, $body);
    $fileData = file_get_contents($my_file, true); //renamed this
    $htmlData = $html->str_get_html($body);
    $tds = $htmlData->find('table',3)->find('td');
    $num = null;
    $i = 0 ;
     foreach($tds as $td){
      $completeArray['magicbricks']['case1'][$i] = $td->innertext; 
                  $i++;          
            }
}
}
return $completeArray;
}
```

Comment: :( of no use. I am new with oops. can you plz check 
 $body = imap_qprint(imap_body($stream,$email_id)); I think $stream is not working its function.